# Login redirect to specific login page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, logout, login-script

I have this code to create a Login/Logout button in the top right header.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    ob_start();
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    } else {
    wp_loginout( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'La mia pagina' ) ) );
    }
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

It works perfectly but when I click on Login it takes me to the wp-login.php with a redirect to 'La mia pagina'.

I'd like it to take me to the new login page I created (title "login" es. https://website.com/login).

I cannot see where to apply these changes. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to `login_url`:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 2 );
function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect ) {
    $url = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'La mia pagina' ) );
    return $url . '?redirect_to=' . $redirect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! Thumbs up for you!